# What is the impact of creating different streams in riemann?

Tags: clojure, monitoring, riemann, riemann-dashboard

I am using riemann and I'm trying to understand the difference/imact of

```
(instrumentation {:enabled? true})
(streams (where (service #"^a\.*") prn) ; stream a
(streams (where (service #"^b\.*") prn) ; stream b
```

vs

```
(streams 
 (where (where (service #"^a\.*") prn)
(where (where (service #"^b\.*") prn)
)
```

What I didn't understand from the [streams](https://github.com/riemann/riemann/blob/main/src/riemann/config.clj#L227)  function is [core](https://github.com/riemann/riemann/blob/bebc6ebd6b98ac2075b6c1a25a9e77452b11889e/src/riemann/config.clj#L70) and [next-core](https://github.com/riemann/riemann/blob/bebc6ebd6b98ac2075b6c1a25a9e77452b11889e/src/riemann/config.clj#L72). Also what is the impact of [reinject](https://github.com/riemann/riemann/blob/bebc6ebd6b98ac2075b6c1a25a9e77452b11889e/src/riemann/config.clj#L281) (I know its not recommended, but what is the impact of reinject in both the different definitions). Is the second approach better? If they are different when is the second approach better than the first?

Still on the path of the clojure learning journey. So some of these things are going on top of the head.